# convert code Text tobe widget from json with flutter code type

Tags: flutter

anyone know how to convert string to widget format?
this is an example what string that we get from server, code from server like this :

```
"result" : "Container(width:100, height:100, color: Color)"
```

to get the result data as a string is easy, but is there any way to convert it into widget?

thanks

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116095/parse-string-to-widget-in-flutter).

Comment: @dm_tr i'm using vsCode